# Single to many analog signals

Tags: analog, switching

I am trying to drive two piezo inkjet print heads with an analog waveform varying from 0-40V, with a slew rate of 15V/us and a complicated waveform of a duration of ~20us. When printing only one nozzle will print at a time but the nozzles will fire in sequence.

I have considered the following circuit (displaying only 3 outputs), an FPGA linked to a DAC will generate the waveform, this will be connected to all 32 nozzles. Firing of a nozzle is carried out by using a transistor (Accidentally picture Darlington) switch also connected to the FPGA.

[image: Initial design of circuit with three outputs, intention is to have 32.]

I believe this circuit although crude would be capable in firing any nozzle with the complex analog waveform, the issue I have is that I would like  a different waveform applied to every nozzle not currently jetting.

For succesful jetting it is required that a constant voltage is applied to all nozzles so a voltage drop is possible during activation. It is imperative that there is no voltage spikes from switching between the "non-printing" and "printing" voltages.

I have considered using a second DAC to generate the constant voltage, that this second DAC is in series with the primary DAC and that a method for switching the second DAC on/off for each channel.

Comment: For the inactive channels do you need a specific dc voltage applied? What voltage? Or do you just need to apply a dc voltage but you don't care what the value is? Would (about) 0 V be okay?

Comment: For the inactive nozzles I will need a dc voltage of 0-10v, the use of the second dac would mean the ability to control this from the FPGA.

Comment: So, basically you want to be able to switch a set of outputs between two different inputs? It sounds like you want an analog MUX (or rather, a set of them, one per output).

Comment: Would there be a drop in voltage during the switch?

Comment: witch Printhead you use?
check the enable option.